# JavaScript heavy app: how to ensure no conflicts with extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm looking for general guidance (eg. bullet points on what to consider) on how to ensure a JavaScript heavy app doesn't run into any conflicts with extensions.

For example, I found that I had a global function called `log`, which a specific extension somehow overwrote. Since extensions can load code at various times, I'm curious what general ideas (or links/articles) people have to ensure no conflicts.

One I've discovered recently is also assume that all 3rd party scripts (from a domain other than yours) may get blocked by some over-zealous Ad Blocker, and act accordingly (eg. always check to ensure any objects or methods you're expecting to be available from those 3rd-party scripts, are in fact available, before calling them).

Appreciate any guidance or ideas here.

As for a specific question:
Is it at all problematic to extend native objects (eg. via `String.prototype.trim = function() { ... };`?

Comment: Try to minimize the use of global variables. You should use modules or self invoking functions wherever possible. You could also keep all your globals under a specific object and operate with that. 

You don't need to to rewrite native objects or prototypes. It's generally a bad practice. You can create your own objects and use those.

Comment: Can you point me to any articles or guides that talk about prototyping native objects not being a good idea? I'd like to learn the reasons for that. I agree that it could cause issues (again, with extensions), but it's also so clean (when the object is native).

Comment: An extension can overwrite or even undo your globals and native object modifications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: Thanks for the link @caisah I'll give this all a read